# How do I Get the HUD?

Tags: 65-million-and-one-bc

In 'Sixty Five Million and One BC', I'm kind of lost without a heads-up display, particularly when I'm just learning how to be a Raptor again.  How can I get this guy to give me his?

[image: Heads up Display]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get if after 3 the stages of the movement tutorial:

1. Run to him by holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>
2. Do a Long Jump by holding <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> in combination with <kbd>↑</kbd>
3. Do an Long Jump Attack, which is similar to a Long Jump, but instead of holding <kbd>↑</kbd> just tap it.

Note that you can talk by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> while facing someone.

Comment: [al](http://xkcd.com/135/)-[so](http://xkcd.com/87/), [rap](http://xkcd.com/292/)-[tors](http://blog.xkcd.com/2007/03/04/velociraptor-safety/)!